# How to parse a mitmdump file?

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I used [this](https://blog.ouseful.info/2019/08/28/intercepting-json-http-responses-to-web-browser-page-requests-using-mitmproxy/) Tony Hirst blog to capture the required data to scrape a website.
But I am only able to extract response for the last one of the flow but there are actually multiple response bodies in the log file.
How to tweak the code to write all the responses in the json created instead of only one?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant code parts you have already developed.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to write an addon that prints out what you are interested in:

```py
def response(flow):
    print(flow.response.text)
```

You can then run this with `mitmdump -r flows.mitm -s printjson.py flowfilter`.